# Powershell rename text files based on strings in text --> More concise way for script?

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to rename bankstatements in MT940-format using the account number and the statement date.

The statements contain the following (example):

```
    :20:
    :25:MHCBNL2AXXX/**0364525123**
    :28C:27/
    :60F:C200207EUR100000,00
    :61:2012311231D0000,1NMSCTOPF1234567890SDD TOPF1234567890
    :86:FR1234567890ARVAL FRANCE
    :62F:C**200207**EUR100000,00
```

I have written the following powershell script by combining some examples but it seems quite long for the purpose.
Question: Is there a concise way to write this script?

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Dropbox\Temp\Gerard\test\*" -Include *.txt, *.ged
 for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
 { 
   $filename = $files[$i].FullName        
  
  #Rename the file based on strings in the file
   $Account =  (Get-Content -Raw -Path $fileName) 
   $Account -match ":25:.+(\d{10})" 
   $Account = $matches[1]

   $StatementDate  =  (Get-Content -Raw -Path $fileName) 
   $StatementDate -match ":62F:C(?<content>.*)EUR"
   $StatementDate  = $matches['content']

   $file=Get-Item $filename
   $file.Basename 
   $extension=$file.Extension
   
   Rename-Item -Path $filename -NewName "$StatementDate-$Account$extension"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have achieved similar with the below:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem '/Users/acc/Downloads/bank/*' -Include '*.txt', '*.ged'
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $File -Raw

    $Account = [Regex]::Match($Content, ':25:.+\*{2}(?<Account>\d{10})\*{2}').Groups['Account'].Value
    $StatementDate = [Regex]::Match($Content, ':62F:C\*{2}(?<StatementDate>\d+)\*{2}EUR').Groups['StatementDate'].Value

    Rename-Item -Path $File -NewName ('{0}-{1}{2}' -f $StatementDate, $Account, $File.Extension)
}
```

- By using the `foreach` loop to iterate over objects in a collection, instead of a `for` (in-range) loop, you gain some aesthetic benefits like being able to easily access object's properties cleanly in the collection.

  - For example, instead of getting an object instance of your file by calling `Get-Item $filename` to only get its extension, it is simplified by using the `foreach` loop and the current iterable is still an object of `System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FileInfo`. Therefore we can get its extension by accessing the current iterable `$File.extension`.
- You were reading from a file multiple times with `Get-Content` where you only needed to do this once for each file.
- In my opinion, using the [.NET `Match()` method of the Regex class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-6.0) is cleaner than using the `-match` operator, but this is personal preference.

  - I did try to use the [`Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0) method so I could pass both regex patterns (split on a pipe `|`) in one call, but for some reason, in both groups returned, not both patterns were matched; one group contained a match for 'Account' whereas it did not for 'StatementDate', and vice versa on the other group.

Comment: Thanks @codaamok, but if I run this then $Account  and $StatementDate are empty (when I replace Rename-Item for Write-Ouput $Account and $StatementDate. 
I checked this because the Rename-Item line caused an error.

Comment: I can only assume the example data isn't representative of your real data. Can you share more? Note in the Regex patterns I'm considerate of `*` characters.

Comment: I'm sorry, Codamok, that was a stupid mistake from me. I intended to make the accountnr and the date in bold and did not notice that it left the ** in. If I change this in the regex it works perfectly. I also found a good explanation of your use of Match and Groups: [link(]https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/30/regex-groups-with-powershell.aspx).
Your help is really much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help @KeesNetelvrees - mark my answer you find it is the correct answer :-)